# how to add mysql table to jar file

Tags: java, maven

I want to add mysql tables into my jar file. How can I do this with maven project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add SQL scripts in `resources`.

Comment: I want to add some values in mysql table when my application is running. That's I do not want to connect database just to use my table in my project. How can I do this ? For example when jar file is created, this file can be also used in any computer which has no mysql.

Comment: then you need to go for pure IO as you are restricted not to use MySQL

Comment: If you are interested in Asp.Net application, there is a MS SQL table,registered users are inserted into, as default. I wonder whether something like this or not in Java ?